# Finding a line or a solution to an equation system

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}-3 & 2 & -1\\0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right].$$

I'm told $(x,y)=(1,1)+t(2,3)$
I understand where the $(1,1)$ part comes from. But not $t(2,3)$

$x=(-1-2y)/2$

$y=(-1+3x)/2$

Where does $t(2,3)$ come from?

Comment: this question is not clear to me. Can you please be more specific?@badatmaths

Comment: @ManjoyDas I'm to parameterise the matrix, or write it in terms of its independent vectors. Or in terms of/y. As is done with the t(2,3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for.
First reduce the matrix $\ A$                       to a row reduced echelon matrix by elementary row operations . 
So
$\ A \xrightarrow{-\dfrac{1}{3}R_{1}}$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  1& -\dfrac{2}{3}& \dfrac{1}{3}\\
  0&0&0
\end{array}
\right] $
This is equivalent to $\ x-\dfrac{2y}{3}=\dfrac{1}{3}$
Here the free variable is $\ y$. So we put $\ y=t$.
Thus $\ x=\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{2}{3}t=\dfrac{1+2t}{3}$
Note: You could also put $\ x=t$ and in that case you would get $\ y=\dfrac {3t-1}{2}$

Comment: @badatmaths if my answer was helpful , please accept my answer